# How To Pass data(List) from one Page to Other in pageview In Flutter I m using Callback for page change Any solution?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, flutter-pageview, fnpagechange

[using callback I am change page in page view I need to pass data also in callback how can I pass data in page view in this call back flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE0Dq.png)

```
Widget buildPageView() {
return PageView(
  controller: pageController,
  onPageChanged: (index) {
    pageChanged(index);
  },
  children: <Widget>[
    TeamList(
      genratePlanPressed: () => pageController.animateToPage(
        1,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ),
    SearchPlayesList(  
        onButtonPressed: () {
      pageController.animateToPage(
        2,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      );
    }),
    SaveFinalGroup(
      onButtonPressed: () {
        pageController.animateToPage(
          0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.linear,
        );
      }
    )
  ],
    physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
);
```

}

Comment: please attach your code snippet not image link

Comment: see i am change  page like this and i want to pass data from one page to othre how can i pass?

Comment: Why do you even need to pass anything? you could just create your list in the buildPageView Widget and update it whenever you need it